# test of proportions, but only want to test the proportion between 2 samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multinomial-distribution

I have a questionnaire with X possible answers (only 1 answer is allowed) an a sample size N.
I want to perform a test of whether answer 1 is more likely than answer 2 for example, regardless of the proportion of the other 3 answers.
I can model that with a multinomial distribution but wondering if there is an easier way to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look only at the $n$ questionnaires with answer 1 or 2. (Other questionnaires have no relevant information.)

A Success occurs if that answer is 1. Suppose there are $s$ successes. Then test whether P(Success) is greater than $p=1/2,$

Example: If $n = 30, s=21,$ then reject $H_0: p=1/2$ vs. $H_a: p>1/2$ at the 5% level because the P-value is $0.021 < 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
sum(dbinom(21:30, 30, .5))
[1] 0.02138697
```

An approximate normal test (say, for cases in which $n$ exceeds a dozen) rejects at level 5% if
$Z = \frac{s - n/2}{\sqrt{n/4}} = \frac{2s - n}{\sqrt{n}} \ge 1.645.$

In the example, that's $Z = 2.19 > 1.645,$ so reject at 5%.

---

**Addendum:** You say you are not interested in proportions of counts for the remaining categories,
but maybe you would feel more comfortable doing
a chi.squared test to see if data are consistent
with all five categories being equally likely.

If those counts are recorded in the vector `ANS`,
then we can do a chi-squared test with null hypothesis
$H_0: p_1=p_2=\cdots=p_5$ against the alternative
that not all five answers are equally likely.

```
ANS = c(21, 9, 12, 27, 31)
chisq.test(ANS)  # equal probs assumed, if no
                 # other alternative given

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  ANS
X-squared = 17.8, df = 4, p-value = 0.00135
```

At this point we 'know' (significance level below 1%)
there are differences among the $p_i.$ Ad hoc, tests
can investigate where the differences lie. Because
we were interested in 1 vs 2 from the start, we do
that ad hoc test first, as below. Notice that only the counts 21 (for `1`s) and 9 (for `2`s) are used.

```
chisq.test(c(21,9))

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  c(21, 9)
X-squared = 4.8, df = 1, p-value = 0.02846
```

This amounts to a test of $p_1 = p_2$ against the two-sided alternative. It is rejected at the 3% level. Has
anything of interest to you been tested or revealed by this
more complicated two-step procedure? (From what you say in your Question, I guess not.)

One potential difficulty is that the overall chi-squared test would sometimes falsely mask an interesting difference
between `1` and `2`.

```
ANS2 = c(21, 9, 15, 16, 14)
chisq.test(ANS2)$p.val
[1] 0.2942
```

[Looking at `1`a and `2`s among 60 questionnaires with respective probabilities $(.75, .25)$ the power of detecting a difference between the two answers is about 98%.
By contrast, looking at all five questions among 150 questionnaires with
respective probabilities $(.3, .1, .2, .2, .2, .2)$ is about 91%.]

Comment: Yeah I understand that if i disregard the other outcomesm its jsut a binomial test, but wonder whats the proper justification of why I can throw away the other questionnaires.Intuitively makes sense

Comment: The questionnaires without 1's or 2's provide no information about the relative frequencies of 1's and 2's. // You asked if there's an 'easier way', and I gave you one. Why are your unhappy? //  Suppose M&M candies rarely put in a piece that's black or white, with a compact car as prize for finding a white one and an expensive vacation as a prize for finding a black one. If you want to know whether winning a car or a vacation is more likely, you're only interested in the few packets containing a white or black piece.